# How to use locks in sections correctly way in OpenMP?

Tags: c, locking, openmp

I must parallelize the following code with 2 locks and output should be in order:
`Hello`
`World`
`Bye`
But when I run the threads are randomly doing the work.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int p;
    omp_lock_t lock;
    omp_init_lock(&lock);
    #pragma omp parallel sections default(shared)
    {
        
        #pragma omp section
        {
            p = omp_get_thread_num();
            omp_set_lock(&lock);
            printf("Th%d: Hello\n",p);
            omp_unset_lock(&lock);
        }

        #pragma omp section
        {   
            p = omp_get_thread_num();
            omp_set_lock(&lock);
            printf("Th%d: World\n",p);
            omp_unset_lock(&lock);
        }

        #pragma omp section
        {
            p = omp_get_thread_num();
            printf("Th%d: Bye\n",p);
        }
    }
    omp_destroy_lock(&lock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes I can use only sections and I must use 2 locks exactly.

Comment: Your lock does _not_ guarantee _ordering_ of your threads--only atomic access to `stdout`. (e.g.) So, for the latter, you'll always get "whole line" output `Hello\n World\n Bye\n` and _not_ `HeWoByllo\ne\nrld\n`. But, with that you _can_ get: `World\n Bye\n Hello\n`. Also, does `default(shared)` mean that `p` is shared? I think `p` needs to be `private` [or needs to be set _inside_ the critical section]. Further, the 3rd section doesn't do any locking. I just ran the program, and got `Th7` on _all_ messages, so [AFAICT], `p` _does_ need to be private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my top comments:

Your lock does *not* guarantee ordering of your threads--only atomic access to `stdout`.

So, for the latter, (e.g.) you'll always get "whole line" output:

```
Hello\n
World\n
Bye\n
```

And, *not*:

```
HeWoByllo\ne\nrld\n
```

But, with that you *can* get:

```
World\n
Bye\n
Hello\n
```

Also, does `default(shared)` mean that `p` is shared? I think `p` needs to be `private` [or needs to be set inside the critical section].

Further, the 3rd section doesn't do any locking.

I just ran the program, and got `Th7` on all messages, so [AFAICT], `p` *does* need to be private.

---

One way to solve this is with a "ticket lock" [*].

**Edit:** After rereading your question, the emphasis on *two* locks may indicate an alternate solution, which I added in the UPDATE below.

Because we can't predict what `p` will be, each section needs a sequence number.

For example, `Hello` needs 1, `World` needs 2, and `Bye` needs 3.

We need to add a shared variable that specifies which section may go next. Each section must loop on that variable [under lock] until it matches its assigned order/sequence number and increment it on the way out to allow the thread that is next in the sequence to run.

[*] A "ticket lock" is modelled on (e.g.) a bakery where you "take a number" when entering and buy stuff when the sign says: "Now serving ..." See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticket_lock

In general, one of the nice things about a ticket lock is that it *guarantees* progress and balanced access. In practice, the number of retries is relatively small/infrequent. This is particularly true if it's implemented using `stdatomic.h` primitives.

Anyway, here's what I came up with:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int p;
    int owner = 1;
    int more = 1;

    omp_lock_t lock;
    omp_init_lock(&lock);

    #pragma omp parallel sections default(shared) private(p) private(more)
    {

        #pragma omp section
        {
            more = 1;
            while (more) {
                p = omp_get_thread_num();
                omp_set_lock(&lock);

                if (owner == 1) {
                    printf("Th%d: Hello\n",p);
                    more = 0;
                    owner += 1;
                }

                omp_unset_lock(&lock);
            }
        }

        #pragma omp section
        {
            more = 1;
            while (more) {
                p = omp_get_thread_num();
                omp_set_lock(&lock);

                if (owner == 2) {
                    printf("Th%d: World\n",p);
                    more = 0;
                    owner += 1;
                }

                omp_unset_lock(&lock);
            }
        }

        #pragma omp section
        {
            more = 1;
            while (more) {
                p = omp_get_thread_num();
                omp_set_lock(&lock);

                if (owner == 3) {
                    printf("Th%d: Bye\n",p);
                    more = 0;
                    owner += 1;
                }

                omp_unset_lock(&lock);
            }
        }
    }

    omp_destroy_lock(&lock);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the program output. The `p` values can vary from run to run, but now, the ordering is *always* the same:

```
Th1: Hello
Th7: World
Th4: Bye
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The above solution is general [and I've used it a number of times in real production code], but it *may* not fit the requirement that you use *two* locks.

What I can think of is to have two locks that are initialized and *locked* by the main thread *before* entering any critical sections.

The first section (`Hello`) needs *no* lock and just goes first. The other two sections (`World` and `Bye`) will first lock on `lock2` and `lock3` respectively.

When `Hello` finishes, it unlocks `lock2`.

This allows `World` to get the lock and run. When finished, it unlocks both `lock2` and `lock3`.

The unlock of `lock3` allows `Bye` to get that lock. It prints and then unlocks `lock3`

Here's what I came up with for that:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int p;

    omp_lock_t lock2;
    omp_init_lock(&lock2);
    omp_set_lock(&lock2);

    omp_lock_t lock3;
    omp_init_lock(&lock3);
    omp_set_lock(&lock3);

    #pragma omp parallel sections default(shared) private(p)
    {
        #pragma omp section
        {
            p = omp_get_thread_num();

            printf("Th%d: Hello\n",p);

            omp_unset_lock(&lock2);
        }

        #pragma omp section
        {
            p = omp_get_thread_num();
            omp_set_lock(&lock2);

            printf("Th%d: World\n",p);

            omp_unset_lock(&lock2);
            omp_unset_lock(&lock3);
        }

        #pragma omp section
        {
            p = omp_get_thread_num();
            omp_set_lock(&lock3);

            printf("Th%d: Bye\n",p);

            omp_unset_lock(&lock3);
        }
    }

    omp_destroy_lock(&lock2);
    omp_destroy_lock(&lock3);

    return 0;
}
```